# Noun + Participle

Tags: participles

I believe that the participle in the following phrase refers to the second noun (rubbish):

*...possible sites with submerged rubbish*

But I have some doubts. Could **"submerged rubbish"** be a participle phrase for **"sites"**? Or are **"sites"** and **"rubbish"** two *independent* parts in this sentence, connected by "with"?

In the phrase *"the idea of putting rubbish into the harbour.."*, **"putting"** is a participle referring to **"idea"**. So, I'm wondering, could it be the same case in the first phrase or not.

Could you please share your opinion on this?

**Edited:**

*Thanks for the correction, "putting" is a gerund*, of course!*

*The second sentence is just another example of a relationship between a noun and a following preposition + modifier + noun. So, the question is if "submerged rubbish" functions as a modifier of "sites"? Or it complements "sites"?*

Comment: "Submerged rubbish" is a noun phrase with "rubbish" as head and the adjective "submerged" as modifier.  The phrase is functioning as complement of the preposition "with".

Comment: Thanks @BillJ , my doubts have been cleared up now!

Comment: @BillJ Do you agree with the comment below that "submerged rubbish" is an adjective describing "sites"?

Comment: "Submerged rubbish" adds information about "sites", but it does **not** modify it; rather, it's a complement of "with." Note that it is a noun phrase, not an adjective.

Comment: @BillJ Ok, thank you!

Comment: @BillJ But isn't "Submerged rubbish" a prepositional phrase? https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/All-About-Prepositional-Phrases#:~:text=A%20prepositional%20phrase%20is%20a,adjectives%2C%20adverbs%2C%20and%20verbs.

Comment: What makes you think it's a preposition phrase, when there's no preposition in it? "Submerged rubbish" is actually a noun phrase. It has the noun "rubbish" as head, and "submerged" as modifier.

Answer (score 1):

> possible sites with submerged rubbish

> the idea of putting rubbish into the harbour

Yes, *submerged* describes *rubbish*.

No.  *submerged rubbish* is a noun phrase and is the object of preposition *with*.  The preposition phrase *with submerged rubbish* acts as an adjective describing *sites*.

In the 'habour' example, *putting* is a **gerund**.  Again, the noun phrase *putting rubbish into the harbour* is the object of preposition *of*, and the preposition phrase *of putting rubbish into the harbour* acts as an adjective describing *idea*.

Edit

*submerged rubbish* is a noun phrase and used in this construction does not modify *site*.  The phrase that acts as an adjective modifying *site* is the preposition phrase *with submerged rubbish*.

*submerged rubbish* functions as complement/object of *with*, not *sites*.

[masterclass](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/what-is-a-prepositional-phrase#3-types-of-prepositional-phrases)
explains the use of prepositional phrases as adjectives.

> Prepositional adjectival phrase: Many prepositions serve as adjective phrases that modify nouns. One such example is "the carpet on the wood floor," where "carpet" is the noun and "on the wood floor" is the modifying adjectival phrase.

Comment: Sorry, yes, "putting" is a gerund! Sorry, if my explanation is a bit confusing. My point was to give the second sentence as another example of a relationship between a noun and a following preposition + modifier + noun. So, after all, "submerged rubbish" functions as a modifier of "sites"? You mentioned that it acts as an adjective. I thought that in the first sentence two nouns are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

"submerged" is a participle, modifying "rubbish".

"submerged rubbish" is a noun phrase, and the object of the preposition "with". It is neither a modifier nor a complement of "sites".  It is a complement of "with".

"with submerged rubbish" is a prepositional phrase. It modifies "sites".

"sites with submerged rubbish" is another noun phrase, composed of a noun "sites", followed by a modifying prepositional phrase.